# How to replace 0 or 0.0 in jsp page with blank space using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

[image]

i am uploding an excel with some values so now my functionality is that there are three tables one contains inserted list,one updated list and one missing fields list.now my functionality is working well but in the missing list the missing fields are taking their default values .So i want to replace those default values with blank spaces. in jstl.i have tried this...

```
 <logic:iterate name="mandetory"   id="mandetoryId" >
    <tr>


      <td width="70%">
      <bean:write name="mandetoryId" property="code" /> 
      </td>
      <td width="70%">
      <bean:write name="mandetoryId" property="description" />
      </td>
      <td width="70%">

       <c:choose>
        <c:if test="${mandetoryId.mrp !=0}">


        </c:if>

        <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="${mandetoryId.mrp==0}"/>

        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose> 
      <bean:write name="mandetoryId" property="mrp" />
      </td>
     <td width="70%">
      <bean:write name="mandetoryId" property="moq" />
      </td>

    </tr>
     </logic:iterate>
```

like my screen shot says the missing list MRP is taking 0 as default value i want to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSTL eq or == to check equality like
in jsp:

```
<%
 double[] array = new double[]{0,0.0,1,2,-1,-2};
 request.setAttribute("array", array);
%>
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <th>MRP</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${array}" var="num">
<tr>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${num eq 0}">
      <td>white space</td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <td>${num}</td>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: can i check 1.0 or 0.0 with this functionality??

Comment: @lucifer yes, you can. in double 0 means 0.0 and same 1 means 1.0. Note: double and float are floating point number types.